# blackberry 5.0 api manager/ui layout

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm trying to come up with a structure for my simple blackberry app. I want to have a static header and 3 containers that will slide into view once the user makes a selection in the previous one. Here is a diagram of it:

[image: app layout]

The red box is the visible screen. The header will be a manager as will each of the content containers. The 3 containers may be inside a manager themselves if it makes it easier to move them around.

My problem is the `Manager` class does not have any methods to do with its own position. I'm a bit stuck as to how I can create this layout. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html) is a base class with very little functionality.

You can start with [VerticalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html) implementation adding two [HorisontalFieldManagers](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) (or vertical).

Also you can start with [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html) (there you already have Title and Banner sections).

See also: [Working with BlackBerry Layout Managers – Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=808)

Comment: Sorry, I realised my initial question wasn't as clear as it could be. When I said `Manager`, I actually meant its subclasses - i.e. `VerticalFieldManager`, `FlowManager`, `AbsoluteFieldManager` etc. I'm stuck on how I would slide from one manager to another.